# In VSCode turn off the following warning Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher

Tags: visual-studio-code

The type script code I am writing compiles just fine. The issue is in visual studio code I see the following warning.

[image]

There is a similar question on SO to this but that is for compiling tyepscript which works . I just see the above warning and I cannot figure out how to turn it off.

I read update your tsconfig.json but as far as I can tell mine is correct.

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In your ts file, if you run the `TypeScript: go to project configuration` command in VS Code, does it open the correct `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @MattBierner this was my problem. For some reason I had a jsconfig.json at the top level of my project (not a tsconfig.json), one level up from where my actual tsconfig.json was. It was going for the jsconfig file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create an application via the angular cli, ng new project, it will create two tsconfig.json one in the root folder of the project and one in the src folder. Web pack when calling ng serve uses the tsconfig.json in the root of the project while vscode uses the one in the src folder.

```
|-tsconfig.json
|-src
  |-tsconfig.json
```

To resolve: update the compiler options for the tsconfig.json in the src folder as follows

add "target": "es2017"

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es2017"
    }
}
```